# How can I optimize the code current algorithm take O(n+m+k)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, python-3.x

I have three arrays, `h1, h2, h3`.

The `n1, n2,n3` decides the length of array.

I have to delete inputs from 1 or more arrays so that, final sum of all the arrays should be same.

```
###Inputs
n1,n2, n3 = 5, 3, 4
h1 = 3 2 1 1 1 # 5 elements
h2 = 4 3 2     # 3 elements
h3 = 1 1 4 1   # 4 elements
```

If we see in the above array

`sum of h1 = 8`
`sum of h2 = 9`
`sum of h3 = 7`
The `deletion should happen` from the beginning of the array.
So here if I delete,
`3 from h1 (as h1[0])`
`4 from h2 (as h2[0])`
`1 and 1 from h3 (as h3[0] and h3[1])`
Now all `(Sum of h1 containts, h2 containts, h3 containts)` the sum will become `5`. This is my final answer.
The below code performs well when the input lists are small. But when input list goes `n1 = 100000, n2 = 200000, n3 = 300000`. This this code takes lots of time to execute. How can I reduce the time.

```
from collections import *
n1,n2,n3 = input().strip().split(' ')
n1,n2,n3 = [int(n1),int(n2),int(n3)]
h1 = [int(h1_temp) for h1_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]
h2 = [int(h2_temp) for h2_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]
h3 = [int(h3_temp) for h3_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]
#print(n1, n2, n3, h1, h2, h3)
h1_tot, h2_tot, h3_tot = sum(h1), sum(h2), sum(h3)
#print(h1_tot, h2_tot, h3_tot)
arr = [h1_tot, h2_tot, h3_tot]
done = False
while len(Counter(arr)) != 1:
    if len(Counter(arr)) == 3:
        if arr.index(min(Counter(arr))) == 0:
            h3.remove(h3[0])
            h2.remove(h2[0])
        elif arr.index(min(Counter(arr))) == 1:
            h3.remove(h3[0])
            h1.remove(h1[0])
        else:
            h1.remove(h1[0])
            h2.remove(h2[0])
    if len(Counter(arr)) == 2:
        index = arr.index(min(arr))
        if arr[0] == arr[1] and  index == 2:
            h1.remove(h1[0])
            h2.remove(h2[0])
        elif arr[1] == arr[2] and index == 0:
            h2.remove(h2[0])
            h3.remove(h3[0])
        elif arr[0] == arr[2] and index == 1:
            h1.remove(h1[0])
            h3.remove(h3[0])
        if arr[0] == arr[1] and (index == 0 or index == 1):
            h3.remove(h3[0])
        elif arr[1] == arr[2] and  (index == 2 or index == 1):
            h1.remove(h1[0])
        elif arr[0] == arr[2] and  (index == 0 or index == 2):
            h2.remove(h2[0])

    h1_tot, h2_tot, h3_tot = sum(h1), sum(h2), sum(h3)

    arr = [h1_tot, h2_tot, h3_tot]



print(arr[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting from the start of a Python list is slow (`O(N)`) because Python needs to copy the references to all the other items to a new index (moving them up one space). In contrast, deleting from the end of a list is fast (`O(1)`) since it just drops one reference and adjusts the size.

So to improve the performance of your algorithm, I'd suggest working with reversed lists so that the items you remove first are at the end. You can reverse them with the `reversed` function in your list comprehension, or using the `list.reverse` method after the lists are created. Once you're done with your algorithm, you can put them back in the expected order by reversing again.

You'll also need to use `list.pop` or `del some_list[-1]` rather than `list.remove`, as the latter will still be slow at the end (since it needs to search through the list for the item to remove).

While I don't think it hurts your performance much, you've also got a lot of very repetitive code. When you see that and you have variables with numbers in them, it's almost always a sign that you can simplify your code a lot by using an indexable data structure, rather than independent variables. Here's how I'd solve your problem using a list of lists (and a list of their sums, for good measure):

```
lengths = [int(x) for x in input().split()] # this is ignored by the rest of the code

values = [[int(x) for x in reversed(input().split())] for _ in range(3)]  # make a list of
sums = [sum(v) for v in values]                                           # reversed lists

while not sums[0] == sums[1] == sums[2]: # if there wasn't a fixed number of lists, I'd use
    max_sum = max(sums)                  # something like "if max(sums) == min(sums)"
    for i, (v, s) in enumerate(zip(values, sums)): # this loop over the lists lets us avoid
        if s == max_sum:                           # duplicating our code for each one
            sums[i] -= v.pop(-1) # pop is fast at the end!

for v in values:  # I'm not sure what the desired output is, so I'm just printing the lists.
    v.reverse()   # Could instead use print(*reversed(v)) for formatting like in the input.
    print(v)
```